# How can I make a bash script to tell if files in a give folder are symlinks or a normal files?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, posix, sh

I have spent the last 5 hours tracking down a bug where symlinked files have been relabelled as normal files (I don't know how!).  I would like to add a verification step to my build script to ensure this doesn't happen again.

In the working environment I get this:

```
> ls -l
... [Info] ...  File1.h -> ../../a/b/File1.h 
... [Info] ...  File2.h -> ../../a/b/File2.h 
...
```

In the corrupted environment I get this:

```
> ls -l
... [Info] ...  File1.h
... [Info] ...  File2.h
...
```

How can I make a robust script to iterate though the files in a folder and ensure that each file is a symlink?

Comment: What do you get if you do `[ -L "File1.h" ] && echo "this is a link"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the file is a link or not with either `-h` or `-L`:

```
if [ -L "$your_file" ]; then
   echo "this is a link"
fi
```

Or shorter,

```
[ -L "$your_file" ] && echo "this is a link"
```

---

From `man test`

> **-h FILE**
>
> FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -L)
>
> **-L FILE**
>
> FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)

Answer (score 1):

This is the full code I went with.  It also searches recursively.

```
for file in $(find Headers/  -name '*.h'); do
    if [ ! -L "$file" ]; then
        echo "Error - $file - is not a symlink.  The repo has probably been corrupted"
        exit 666 # evil exit code for an evil bug
    fi
done
```